# PHP JOIN Two MySQL table in result

Tags: php, mysql, join

I have two MySQL table for insert comment data and reviews data like this :

comments:

```
|id|post_id|text|name|timestamp|approved|parent_id|type|ip|
```

reviews:

```
|id|postID|comments_id|reviewfield1|reviewfield2|reviewfield3
```

in action I insert for each comments One reviews. Now, I need to show/print comment list with comment `name` and `text` + `reviewfield1` `reviewfield2` `reviewfield3` for each comments where comments is `approved` like this :

```
 commenter 1 
  text
  reviewfield1
  reviewfield2
  reviewfield3
```

TRY:

```
"SELECT name,text,timestamp FROM " . COMMENTS . " LEFT JOIN " . REVIEWS . " WHERE " . COMMENTS . ".id = " . REVIEWS . ".comments_id AND
        post_id = ? AND type = ? AND approved = 1 ", $id, $type"
```

But this not work for me. how do generate this with PHP `JOIN` method?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: you are a smart guy. You got this far. Keep going

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/join.html

Comment: @Ahmad: please see my edit.

Comment: @Drew: I add my code.

Comment: `LEFT JOIN` requires `ON`, not `WHERE`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are making mistake in the query. It must be like this:

```
"SELECT name,text,timestamp,reviewfield1 FROM " . COMMENTS . " LEFT JOIN " . REVIEWS . " ON " . COMMENTS . ".id = " . REVIEWS . ".comments_id WHERE
        post_id = ? AND type = ? AND approved = 1 ", $id, $type"
```

And you can select rows from the second(joined) table, same as the first one.

Comment: u right. how do print any field from second(reviews) table like : 'reviewfield1' or 'reviewfield2'?